How to use LaTeX to draw the dominance order diagram of Young diagrams as shown below?
This is the case for n=6 that I found on Wikipedia. Now, I want to draw the case for n=7. Although I can manually plot the desired squares in a coordinate system and position them correctly, then add the corresponding arrows, I believe this is not the most efficient method. Is there a more elegant and efficient way to draw such a diagram?


Welcome to TeX SE. What have you tried? What should it look like. Not everyone here is familiar with Young diagrams.

Perhaps there’s no need to involve too much specialized knowledge about Young diagrams here. It’s just a collection of squares connected by arrows.

Have a look at the positioning library from tikz and the package https://ctan.org/pkg/ytableau

Welcome. // Perceive your diagram as a 3-column layout, much like a table. If you go the Tikz route, the matrix environment allows you to place \nodes where the thingies will be. It allows you to vary both x- and y-separations. It allows you to draw (bend) lines. A node can contain any Latx-text, e.g. from said package https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728393/how-to-use-latex-to-draw-the-dominance-order-diagram-of-young-diagrams-as-shown#comment1813512_728393 . // Now read the turorials in https://tikz.dev/ , esp. https://tikz.dev/tutorial-chains#sec-5.3 . Done (conceptually)

could you post your solution as an answer instead? it messes up the q&a format to put answers inside questions. for example, anybody looking for the same thing will see this has no answers and assume there's no solution to be found here.

Thanks to everyone's help, I did it! Below is the code I implemented and the result I achieved.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows.meta}
\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in, top=0.3in, bottom=0.2in}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\matrix(m)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, row sep=0.6cm,                                                 column sep=0.6cm] {
& & \yng(7) & & \\
& & \yng(6,1) & & \\
& & \yng(5,2) & & \\
& \yng(5,1,1) & & \yng(4,3) & \\
& & \yng(4,2,1) & & \\
& \yng(4,1,1,1) & & \yng(3,3,1)  & \\
& & \yng(3,2,2) & & \\
& & \yng(3,2,1,1) & & \\
& \yng(3,1,1,1,1) & & \yng(2,2,2,1) & \\
& & \yng(2,2,1,1,1) & & \\
& & \yng(2,1,1,1,1,1) & & \\
& & \yng(1,1,1,1,1,1,1) & & \\
};

\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-1-3) -- (m-2-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-2-3) -- (m-3-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-3-3) -- (m-4-2);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-3-3) -- (m-4-4);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-4-2) -- (m-5-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-4-4) -- (m-5-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-5-3) -- (m-6-2);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-5-3) -- (m-6-4);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-6-4) -- (m-7-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-7-3) -- (m-8-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-6-2) -- (m-8-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-8-3) -- (m-9-2);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-8-3) -- (m-9-4);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-9-4) -- (m-10-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-9-2) -- (m-10-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-10-3) -- (m-11-3);
\draw[-{Stealth}] (m-11-3) -- (m-12-3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}



thanks for reorganising!
